# Add element to list in class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm still wrestling with classes. Instead of using the classic employees in a company or car example, I've decided to create a simple game character. So far so good, only I'm having trouble adding to an item to a list which is a class.

```
class Player():
  def __init__(self, name, items):
    self.name   = name
    self.items  = items

# initialize character
player = Player("Joey", 
  ["movie stub", "keys", "army man"])


print(player.items)
# >> ['movie stub', 'keys', 'army man'] # this is fine
```

Now I'd like to add an item to the player character.

```
player.items.push("a rock")
# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'push'
```

I was trying using push - only that results in an attribute error. So I added a simple helper class:

```
# helper class
class List(list):
  def push(self, x):
    self.append(x)

player.items = List(["a rock"])
```

Yay! no errors...

```
print(player.items)
>> ['a rock']
```

Only instead of appending, it's replaced the list, which is *not* what I'm after.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `insert(index)` – inserts a single element anywhere in the list.
`append()` – always adds items (strings, numbers, lists) at the end of the list.
`extend()` – adds iterable items (lists, tuples, strings) to the end of the list.

Comment: Can you explain *why* it is so important to be able to call `append` by the name `push` instead of just using `append` directly? I know it's called `push` in other languages, but you're not writing those languages; trying to write code from language X in language Y leads to *terrible* code (all the people who come from C and only write `for` loops over `range`s, the people who come from Perl and never use `str` methods, just the `re` module, etc.). Your original problem would not be an issue if you were willing to just type `player.items.append("a rock")`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger in this instance (pun intended) it wasn't  a python/javascript append/push name transposition but simply using a synonym and unable to comprehend that I was doing anything wrong. A problem with English and not code; happens all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You should add push function inside the class itself

```
class Player():
  def __init__(self, name, items):
    self.name   = name
    self.items  = items

  def push(self, x):
    self.items.append(x)

  def print(self):
    print(self.name,": ",self.items)


# initialize character
player = Player("Joey", 
  ["movie stub", "keys", "army man"])
```

adding item to the list

```
player.push("a rock")
```

printing

```
player.print()
```

output

> Joey :  ['movie stub', 'keys', 'army man', 'a rock']

Answer (score 1):

To be fair you're complicating things. Just made method in class, which add things to your list and you're good to go

```py
class Player():
  def __init__(self, name, items):
    self.name   = name
    self.items  = items
  def add_item(item):
    self.items.append(item)
```

With this

```py
# helper class
class List(list):
  def push(self, x):
    self.append(x)

player.items = List(["a rock"])
```

you weren't even passing list you wanted to attach item.
So to make your helper work(you do not need it, method in Player is good enough, but I want to show it anyway, because you asked for it)

```py
class List():
  def push(self, list, x):
    list.append(x)
```

my advise is to put method in class player to append there items

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to replace it, don't replace it? There is nothing special about the name `push`, and you never called it, so `append` never occurred, you just replaced the original `list` with your unnecessary `List` subclass.

If you *must* be able to call `push` instead of `append`, convert to your `List` subclass on construction, so it stores a `push` friendly `list` from the get-go:

```
class List(list):
  def push(self, x):
    self.append(x)

class Player():
  def __init__(self, name, items):
    self.name   = name
    self.items  = List(items)
```

Now you can just do:

```
player = Player("Joey", 
                ["movie stub", "keys", "army man"])

player.items.push("a rock")
```

and it just works. As a side-benefit, it is now shallow-copying the `list` provided by the caller, so change's made to the caller's `list` don't retroactively change the instance's attribute's contents, nor vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a more complete OOP approach by encapsulating data and functionality within your class. Something like this:

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, items):
        self._name = name
        self._items = items
    def push(self, item):
        self._items.append(item)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self._name=}, {self._items=}'
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Name={self._name}, Items={", ".join(self._items)}'

player = Player("Joey", ["movie stub", "keys", "army man"])
print(player)
player.push('a rock')
print(player)
```

**Output:**

```
Name=Joey, Items=movie stub, keys, army man
Name=Joey, Items=movie stub, keys, army man, a rock
```